# Ошибка с библиотекой brawlstars.py

Tags: python, discord.py, discord, библиотеки, brawlstars.py

У меня есть код:

```
import asyncio
import discord
from discord.ui import View, Button
from discord.utils import get
from discord import *
from discord.ext import tasks, commands
import brawlstars as bs

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='%', intents=discord.Intents.all())
bot.remove_command('help')

@bot.command()
async def pstat(ctx, playertag):
    player = bs.Client.get_player(self=Client ,tag=playertag)
    club = bs.Client.get_club(self=Client, tag=playertag)
    if club is not None:
        em = discord.Embed(title="Статистика игрока: ", discription=("Клан игрока: ", f"{club}"))

bot.run("MTE1OTU0ODMxODkzNDg5Njc1Mg.G-vULE.8Jry9yNBg8Zp8vLg968iAHNLvlb6-U7VWVruBo")
```

При вводе команды выходит ошибка:

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: type object 'Client' has no attribute 'session'
```

Вопрос - как исправить? Прошу помочь как сможете пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если не ошибаюсь, нужно так:

```
client = bs.Client("токен, полученный на https://developer.brawlstars.com/")
player = client.get_player("тег игрока")
```

Comment: Переделал код под ваш, используя токен с сайта, но появилась еще одна ошибка: discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: ResourceNotFoundError: resource was not found.

Comment: Вы тег не вставили:)

Comment: Но там 2 аргумента: token и session. В token я вставил токен с сайта, а в session я так и не понял что вставлять.

Comment: Та не, не `session`. Вы в `get_player()` тег вставили? С хештегом?

Comment: Да, тэг там есть, но он вставляется через ввод с клавиатуры. Тоесть я просто переменную туда поставил а переменная вводится с клавиатуры. И при это вот такая ошибка возникает

Comment: Он также кроме атрибута tag требует self:

player = client.get_player(tag=playertag, self=)

Что там должно быть я незнаю.

Comment: спасибо большое за любую помощь! Все заработало!